# How to drag from a background window to the front window

Tags: nautilus, focus, drag-and-drop

Is the following I will explain possible with a key combination?

Here is the image:

[image]

As you can see, the terminal is the focus window (Front window) and Nautilus is in the background (Back Window). How can I grab a folder or file from Nautilus without loosing focus on the terminal (Without making the terminal go to the background and Nautilus to the front) and drop it in the terminal?. What I want is not to have to ALT+TAB again just to do this.

Options like resizing the windows to fit the screen are not what I am looking for. Like in the image, we have a fullscreen window that we want it to stay like that. We can drag the terminal window around but anytime I access the background nautilus window, I should not loose focus on the terminal (It should not go to the background every time I access Nautilus). Maybe like a key combination that freezes the current focus windows positions and I can drag from background windows to background windows or background windows to the front focused one.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/307433/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-a-file-into-a-window-thats-not-in-the-foreground

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the Terminal title-bar and select Always On Top.  You can now drag files from Nautilus to Terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Responsible for this behaviour on all windows is Metacity. By opening **gconf-editor** we can disable it.

**Note that you then will no longer be able to raise any window by clicking on it.**

[image]

Comment: Nicely done Takkat. Is there a way to for example create a shortcut that will enable/disable this option whenever the keys are pressed. For example leaving SUPER+Z pressed will enable the feature while I drag stuff and then after releasing will activate the option again.

Comment: You may be able to call **gconftool-2** from a keyboard shortcut to set `raise_on_click` but as soon as you update to 12.10 this will probably not work any more.

Comment: Your answer is correct. But it has some buggy feature :P

Comment: A much better approach would be to get the windows manager to raise a window on mouse button **release** rather than on click. But afaik this is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but I just resize the windows and put them side-by-side. Like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: No. That would involve resizing the windows. The question is to not be able to resize them, just grab something from the background window without the front one loosing focus.. Resizing will just eat time to do a simple drag or copy/paste. I will add this to the question to clarify.