# How do I drag-and-drop a file into a window that's not in the foreground?

Tags: unity, gui, window-manager, drag-and-drop

In Windows, if I'm dragging a file or a piece of text and I want to want to drop it into a window that's currently not in the foreground I can simply hover over that window on the task bar and the appropriate window will come to the foreground. I just tried doing this on Ubuntu and it didn't work. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can press and hold the file with mouse click and then press Ctrl+Tab to bring that windows to foreground.
If you have Nautilus 3.4.2 or older, press F3 and then drag and drop file from one pane to other pane.

Comment: This works for moving files between tabs in Nautilus, but not for (for example) dragging a file from a maximized Nautilus window into my browser. (http://askubuntu.com/questions/194840/how-to-drag-from-a-background-window-to-the-front-window?lq=1)